# Merge "networking" into "network"

Tags: support, tags

This is a simple duplicate—overlaps in description and scope. ([networking](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) → [network](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done it the other way around, since [networking](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) was more popular.